# Write xsd:type attribute in Apache XmlBeans

Tags: java, xml, apache, xmlbeans

About Apache XmlBeans. I use AnyType in scheme definition (xsd:anyType) as element in complex type.
Example:

```
<request xmlns="">    
<xml>
  <input1>
    <string>str</string>
  </input1>
</xml>
</request>
```

in java code

```
final ProcessRequest processRequest = requestDocument.addNewRequest();
XmlObject xml = processRequest.addNewXml();
xml.changeType(operationType.type);
xml.set(operationType);
```

and i want to see

```
<xml xsd:type="*opeation1NSPrefix*:*operation1Type*>
...
</xml>
```

but i see only `<xml/>`. What i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

stupid mistake: operation1 define as anonymous type `<element><complexType>..</></>` in wsdl. when i define `"<element type=".."/><complexType name=".."/>` the problem disappeared